# NSDateformatter setDateFormat according to currentLocale

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, nsdateformatter, nslocale

I'm going mad with, probably, a stupid problem.

I have 3 strings: year, month and day. I need to have a date in the right format based on currentLocale, so i.e. if currentLocale localeIdentifier is en_US my dateFormat should be:
MMM/dd/yyyy

if it's fr_FR the dateFormat should be dd/MMM/yyyy

I don't think the only way to do this is to get currentLocale localeIdentifier and start with a bunch of if then.

Thanks in advance.

Max

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at NSDateComponents to create an NSDate, then use NSDateFormatter to format it. NSDateFormatter uses the current locale to format dates, based on the format style (e.g.
`NSDateFormatterMediumStyle`).

Comment: Thank you much. NSDateComponents helped.

Answer (score 34):

If I understand your question, you want to set your `NSDateFormatter` to the locale of the user's device. For that you can just do something like this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 3:

```swift
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .medium
formatter.timeStyle = .none
formatter.locale = Locale.current
let date = Date()
let dateString = formatter.string(from: date)
print(dateString)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-(NSString *) stringFromDate:(NSDate *) date{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    [dateFormatter release];

    return dateString;
}

-(NSDate *) dateFromString:(NSString *) dateInString{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateInString];

    [dateFormatter release];

    return dateFromString;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

check out this link to get understand of how `NSDateFormatter` based on http://www.codingexplorer.com/swiftly-getting-human-readable-date-nsdateformatter/

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to have more flexibility about the format than the formats usable with setDateStyle, have a look at my answer to a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20219610/1896336